# Issue Installing Rails With RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

rvm list shows me:

```
ruby-1.9.3-head [ x86_64 ]  
ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]  
ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
```

---

`rails server` is only supported on ruby-1.9.3-head, but not on p125 or p194, who give me the following errors, respectively, when running a rails command like "rails s":

```
p125: Could not find activesupport-3.2.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

upon running bundle install, I get:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find jquery-rails-2.0.0 in any of the sources

p194: /$usr_path/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find activesupport-3.2.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to tell what is the problem, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help - for hints on formatting your question - so it's more clear what is error / command / text

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$ bundle install` failed so `activesupport 3.2.6` was not successfully installed. As you can see [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-rails/versions), `jquery-rails 2.0.0` was yanked, that's why you see the "Could not find jquery-rails-2.0.0 in any of the sources" error.

Open `Gemfile` and update the version of `jquery-rails` to "2.0.1" or "2.0.2". Re-run `$ bundle install` then all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing RVM on mountain lion

Simply run

```
bundle update
```

to fix the problem!

Comment: This is dangerous and will update all of your gems. A safer route would be to `bundle update jquery-rails` then you will only be updating jquery-rails and its dependencies.